# What does "as" mean in "the same room as him"?

Tags: prepositions, word-meaning, conjunctions

> I didn't even want to fall asleep in the same room as him.

It seems that "as" can be replaced with "with". Does it mean "with"? But I found nothing about the "with" meaning in "as" of dictionaries.

Or, it is a conjunction meaning in the same way? But I can't make sure if a conjunction can link a word

By the way, the source is [r/nosleep: Ever since I woke up from surgery, everyone tells me that I’m married to a man I’ve never met](https://www.reddit.com/r/nosleep/comments/112j4ep/ever_since_i_woke_up_from_surgery_everyone_tells/)

Comment: [The same as](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-same-as) is a set phrase in English. It can also be used with a word in between - _Your sweater is the same colour as mine. He is in the same situation as she is._

Comment: There's something a bit weird / tautologous about *I live in the **same** house **with** him*. It makes me want to ask *Same as **what**?*

Comment: With in your example is no different to "I didn't even want to fall asleep with him." It doesn't mean "as", it means something like "in close proximity to".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is separated by "room" though, It is a variant of a set phrase in English for "The same as".

There are many examples.

- Your sweater is the same colour as mine.
- Linda isn't the same height as Jenny.
  etc

In my opinion, "as him" after "the same" is the comparative adverb in the sentence.